# Android: SVG isn't rendering correctly

Tags: android, svg, android-imageview

When I render SVG from res/raw picture representation is not what it should be.
I'm using com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVG.

Here's my code:

```
   public void drawImage(ImageView imageView) {
    SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getActivity().getResources(),  R.raw.svg_tables);
    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(800, 600, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.setDensity((int) displayMetrics.xdpi);
    canvas.drawPicture(svg.getPicture(), new Rect(0, 0, 800, 600));
    final BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
}
```

It should look like this:

[image: How it should look]

How it actually looks:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to post the SVG? Either here or in a jsfiddle?  There may be something in the file that svg-android doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the latest one

https://bitbucket.org/paullebeau/androidsvg/downloads

It is having an SVGImage vie in it...